# How to assign pod IP to a container's argument field in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I am going to utilize the pod IP environment variable in my K8s deployment so that the pod IP should be assigned to a container's argument which is listening on this IP. I tried to fetch pod IP via "status.podIP" and retrieve it in the arg section as follow:

```
env:
 - name: MY_POD_IP
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: status.podIP
```

the container is a proxy application which is listening on the pod IP and its own port number.

```
- args:
   - --listen=MY_POD_IP:XXXX
```

But this setup sometimes returns a binding error as:

> bind: cannot assign requested address

and sometimes the server error as:

> listen tcp: lookup MY_POD_IP: server misbehaving

If I replace the MY_POD_IP with the actual pod IP, the setup works fine, but since this pod IP is generated dynamically in every deployment, I need to have a general solution to assign this IP to my argument. Any idea or workaround?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
- args:
   - --listen=$(MY_POD_IP):XXXX
```

Ref: [Use environment variables to define arguments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but the error changed to: "[error] listen tcp: lookup "172.17.0.17": no such host". The pod ip is correct, but it could not be assigned to the args.

Comment: what is your `:XXXX` part?

Comment: can you try `--listen=$(MY_POD_IP):XXXX`  or `--listen="$(MY_POD_IP):XXXX"` ?

Comment: XXXX is the container's port number, the port that I want the container to listen.

Comment: I got this error now: listen tcp: address tcp/XXXX": unknown port

Comment: OK, now it is working without quotation mark like this: listen=$(MY_POD_IP):XXXX.   Thank you so much indeed.